# A family of sets closed under difference is closed under intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was propposed to prove that a family of sets that is closed under difference is also closed under finite intersection.

At my understading, this is easy to prove provided my family of sets is a ring. Indeed, given $A, B$ on the family,
$$A\cap B = (A\cup B)- \{(A-B)\cup(B-A)\}.$$
Since $A, B$ lie on the family, that is closed under difference, $A\cap B$ lies on the family if, and only if, $A\cup B$ also belongs to the family.
The problem is that I do not have this information. How to proceed?

Comment: Suppose both $A$ and $B$ are in the collection.  Since both $A$ and $B$ are in the collection and the collection is closed under set differences, this implies $A\setminus B$ is in the collection as well.  Now... since $B$ is in the collection and $A\setminus B$ is also in the collection and the collection is closed under taking set differences...

Comment: @JMoravitz, $A-B$ is on the collection, but $A-(A-B) = A\cap B$, right?

Comment: this is true by De Morgans law, since $A-(A-B) = A\cap (A\cap B^c)^c = A\cap (A^c\cup B) = A\cap B.$

Comment: Yes... if you allow yourself to be in a universe where taking set complements makes sense.  I prefer to word it without making any reference to complements in the first place, but you will arrive again at $A\setminus(A\setminus B)=A\cap B$ so we learn that if $A$ and $B$ are in a collection closed under set differences that $A\cap B$ must also be in the set, implying that such a collection must also be closed under intersection.

Comment: Now... as for $A\cap B$ in the family iff $A\cup B$ is in the family, I do not think this is true *solely* given that the set is closed under differences (*and thus intersections*).  You will need that it is closed under complements (*and thus have a universal set defined*) as well to get that if I remember correctly.  E.g. $\{\{1\},\{2\},\emptyset\}$ is a collection which is closed under set difference and intersection.

Comment: Thank you very much @JMoravitz, please, consider posting it as an answer, It would be a pleasure to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both elements of our family of sets which is closed under set difference.  It follows that $A\setminus B$ is also an element of our family.

It follows then that $A\setminus (A\setminus B)=A\cap B$ is an element of our family and so our family is also closed under intersection.

> For proving that set identity, remember that $A$ can be partitioned as $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)$, that is to say given an arbitrary element of $A$, it is either also in $B$ or it is not in $B$.

---

Note, the given conditions in the problem do not mention the existence of a universal set, nor do they mention that the universal set must be in our collection.  As such, it does not follow that our collection must also be closed under union.  For example, $\{\{1\},\{2\},\emptyset\}$ is a perfectly valid collection of sets closed under set difference and intersection despite that the set $\{1,2\}$ is missing.

Also, although being closed under difference implies being closed under intersection, the converse is not true.  $\{\{1\}\}$ is a perfectly valid family closed under intersection, but it is not closed under difference since the empty set is missing.

It is only after you additionally include as a hypothesis that $\emptyset$ and $X$ (*our universal set*) are elements of our family as well alongside the original hypothesis that the family is closed under differences that we get that the set is closed under complements and unions too.